# Cast name of a class while importing to prevent for "is not a constructor" error

Tags: node.js

Is it possibile to cast a name of exported class while importing?

export:

```
class ResponseObj {}
const TYPES = {}
module.exports = { ResponseObj, TYPES };
```

and import:

```
const { response, responseTypes } = require(cfg.libs + 'message_response');
```

now I get error "response is not a constructor" while run:

```
var n = new response()
```

How can I cast it only for one file and leave as is ({ ResponseObj, TYPES }) for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { ResponseObj:response , TYPES:responseTypes } = require(cfg.libs + 'message_response');
```

is what you are looking for.

More generally,

```
const { exportedKey: newKeyName } = require('something);

// use newKeyName this file
```